# How to not trigger onBlur when dropdown is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown component that autocompletes email inputs on click.

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './email-select-box.module.scss'

const EmailSelectBox = ({ email, setEmail, setShowEmailList }) => {
  return (
    <ul className={styles.emailSelectBox}>
      <li onClick={() => { setShowEmailList(false); setEmail(`${email}@gmail.com`) }}>{email}@gmail.com</li>
      <li onClick={() => { setShowEmailList(false); setEmail(`${email}@naver.com`) }}>{email}@naver.com</li>
      <li onClick={() => { setShowEmailList(false); setEmail(`${email}@hanmail.com`) }}>{email}@hanmail.net</li>
      <li onClick={() => { setShowEmailList(false); setEmail(`${email}@hotmail.com`) }}>{email}@hotmail.com</li>
    </ul>
  )
}

export default EmailSelectBox
```

The component is used in the following context

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import EmailSelectBox from '../../components/email-select-box'
import styles from './b-type-05.module.scss'

const Input = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [showEmailList, setShowEmailList] = useState(false)

  const openEmailList = () => {
    setShowEmailList(true)
    // delete email options (ex: @gmail.com) when input is clicked
    setEmail(email.replace(/@.*/g, ''))
  }

  return (
    <div className="form-wrap input-wrap  form-info-wrap" onBlur={() => {setShowEmailList(false)}}>
      <input type="text" title="" placeholder="ex) abc@abc.com" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} onClick={() => { openEmailList() }} />
      {showEmailList && (
        <EmailSelectBox email={email.replace(/@.*/g, '')} setEmail={setEmail} setShowEmailList={setShowEmailList} />
      )}
      {email && (
        <span className='tc-blue form-info'>
          Please check your email for spelling errors :)
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I would like the `EmailSelectBox` dropdown to disappear when the user

1. Clicks on an email option
2. Clicks away from the input field

I resolved 1) by activating `setShowEmailList(false)` whenever an email option is clicked.

I thought using `onBlur={() => {setShowEmailList(false)}}` on the parent `div` would resolve 2), but what happens is that when the `EmailSelectBox` dropdown is clicked, the dropdown disappears before it can activate `setEmail` and autocomplete the email address.

My bandaid solution was to add a separate `handleBlur` function

```
  const handleBlur = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowEmailList(false)
    }, 300)
  }
```

and pass it to my parent `div`

```
<div className="form-wrap input-wrap  form-info-wrap" onBlur={handleBlur}>
```

This "works", as the dropdown immediately disappears when it is clicked after updating the email state. But there is a notable delay of the dropdown disappearing when the user clicks aways from the input. And if I set the `setTimeout` time to be `100`, there is a risk that the the dropdown disappears before updating the email state.

Why is this bug occurring and is there a cleaner solution to my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, I used the `onMouseDown` event (it doesn't work with `onClick`), then I caught the event (`e`) and I prevented it :

```
const EmailSelectBox = ({ email, setEmail, setShowEmailList }) => {
  return (
    <ul className={styles.emailSelectBox}>
      <li onMouseDown={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setShowEmailList(false); setEmail(`${email}@gmail.com`) 
      }}>{email}@gmail.com</li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Is this working for you too ?